# Execute managed AWS Config rule on demand via SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-net, aws-config

Is it possible to run a managed AWS Config rule (for example https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/root-account-mfa-enabled.html) on demand via the SDK?

Scenario:
As a consultant I want to easily assess a customer's environment without spending time applying all the AWS Config rules to my customer's environment. Instead I want to use the SDK to quickly execute many rules and get the results back.

Is this possible?

Comment: I'd look at Cloud Custodian. Well it can do aws config rules I'm betting it would be a great fit for some of the more adhoc run type work you might need and has good documentation and lots of great features.

Comment: Added more detail as an actual answer now that I'm not on mobile. Please update your results if you end up finding this useful, as I'll probably dive back into Cloud Custodian in the near future myself. I think it reduces a lot of the complexity of AWS specific services so I'm betting it's going to get you moving faster.

Comment: Did this help? I didn't see any accepted answer so I'm interested in knowing how it worked out

Answer (score 0):

### Cloud Custodian

For adhoc execution you might be best served by evaluating [Cloud Custodian](https://cloudcustodian.io/) instead. When I tried this out previously, I was pretty impressed with the immediate value I could get with minimal deployment.

The adhoc nature of your execution can benefit as you can run a report only action, or actually have it create lambda functions to remediate in certain cases if you need that.

The tool is cross platform, dockerized as well, and most of the configuration for rules is yaml based, supporting AWS Config, Security Hub, AWS SSM, and more.

If you look at the [Run Your First Policy section in AWS](https://cloudcustodian.io/docs/aws/gettingstarted.html#run-your-policy) you'll see it can be as simple as:

```sh
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="foo" AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="bar" custodian run --output-dir=. custodian.yml
```

There is a pretty extensive list of [example-policies](https://cloudcustodian.io/docs/aws/examples/index.html) which include items like

### AWS Config Integration

> - Can be deployed as config-rule for any resource type supported by config.
> - Can use config as resource database instead of querying service describe apis. Custodian supports server side querying resources with Config’s SQL expression language.
> - Can filter resources based on their compliance with one or more config rules.
> - Can be deployed as a config-poll-rule against any resource type supported by cloudformation.
>   source: [AWS Config Integration](https://cloudcustodian.io/docs/aws/topics/config.html#aws-config)

It supports custom config rules as well.

Note: I'm not involved in the project, just found it useful and promising for similar situations as you describe. Seems to reduce a lot of "DevOps plumbing" required to get value out of several AWS services with far less service specific knowledge and setup required.